# Mass Transit DiscardSkippedMessages on Azure Service Bus topic - how to completly ignore unknown message types

Tags: c#, events, azureservicebus, messaging, masstransit

I am struggling to understand the DiscardSkippedMessages setting on my ASB topic subscription endpoint.

### Summary:

From what I understand, if the message type is unknown to the subscriber or has no consumers registered, the message is skipped. According to MT docs, this message should go to "xxx_skipped" queue by default. I should be able to adjust this behavour to complelty discard it, or raise an exception.

I may misunderstand what "discard" means in this context. I'd expect that the message is acknowledged and forgotten, however it goes to the dead letter queuee instead.

### Context:

I am working on a solution where we have already defined topics. Single topic may have multiple message types. MT supports this without any issues, however this architecture raises a problem when it comes to future deployments. When a publishing application sends a new event, all consumers that happen to be subscribed to given topic will need to have an empty handler:

```
subConfig.Handler<EventIAmNotInterestedIn>(_ => Task.CompletedTask);
```

We want to stick to the current architectire where single topic can have multiple releted event types. This is why I started to investigate how to complelty ignore any message that has no known consumers. DiscardSkippedMessages seemed like exectly what I wanted.

All Fault<> are setup to land in a different topic. 
We are using version 7.3.0 of Mass Transit.

### Question 1:

Difference between *_skipped* queue and *dead letter* queue in Azure Service Bus.

I'd assume that default configuration of MT would result in this queue being created, however the skipped messages are going to *dead letter*. Does this implies, that *_skipped* queue is a thing in other thansports, but for ASB it is *dead letter*?

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.MinimumLevel.Debug();
            configuration.WriteTo.Console();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(mtConfig =>
            {                        
                mtConfig.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                // minimal working configuration
                mtConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busConfig) =>
                {
                    busConfig.Host(ConnectionString);

                    busConfig.SubscriptionEndpoint(
                        "testsub",
                        "some.topic",
                            subConfig =>
                            {
                                subConfig.ConfigureConsumer<SomeEventConsumer>(context);
                            });



                    busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });

            services.AddHostedService<BusHostedService>();

        })
        .Build()
        .RunAsync();
}
```

where *BusHostedService* is used only to start/stop the bus. I am submitting messages manually with Azure Service Bus Explorer.

```cs
internal class BusHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IBusControl _bus;
    public BusHostedService(IBusControl bus)
    { _bus = bus; }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _bus.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _bus.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

When I submit a message with a unknown type it is skipped as expected:

```json
{
  "messageId": "e934af95-33ea-4df0-a793-62f9e488e78d",
  "correlationId": "75694f2c-ea53-4568-887b-1b5abbade1c2",
  "conversationId": "66700000-cd86-922e-fc03-08da7096c7ea",
  "sourceAddress": "sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/***",
  "destinationAddress": "sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/***",
  "messageType": [
  "urn:message:SomeNamespace:UnknownEvent"   <---- this type does not exist and have no consumer
  ],
  "message": { },
  "sentTime": "2022-07-28T12:43:32.7704944Z",
  "headers": { },
  "host": {
    "machineName": "6a13b9ccde39",
    "processName": "***",
    "processId": 8,
    "assembly": "***",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.603.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "6.0.7",
    "massTransitVersion": "7.3.0.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Unix 5.4.0.1074"
  }
}
```

In logs I can see that it was skipped:

```
[11:12:57 DBG] Hosting starting
[11:12:58 INF] Configured endpoint testsub, Consumer: MTProducer.SomeEventConsumer
[11:12:58 DBG] Starting bus: ***
[11:12:59 DBG] Endpoint Ready: ****
[11:13:00 DBG] Topic: some.topic ()
[11:13:00 DBG] Subscription testsub (some.topic -> null)
[11:13:00 DBG] Endpoint Ready: sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/some.topic/Subscriptions/testsub
[11:13:00 INF] Bus started: sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/
*[11:13:13 DBG] SKIP sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/some.topic/Subscriptions/testsub 54d1e792-0ea6-42a0-b93f-1fa8d1d3b3d4*
```

and I can see that it landed in *dead letter*, no *_skipped* queue was created
[screenshot showing a topic and subscription with single item in dead letter queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3QYc.png)

So, does this mean that for ASB the default way of dealing with skipped messages is to put them into *dead letter* queue?

### Question 2:

Since we already established what default configuration does, I want to discard this message. I'd like to have it complelty forgotten and not sent into dead letter.

I will do it with DiscardSkippedMessages method.

```cs
mtConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busConfig) =>
{
    busConfig.Host(ConnectionString);

    busConfig.SubscriptionEndpoint(
        "testsub",
        "some.topic",
            subConfig =>
            {
                subConfig.DiscardSkippedMessages();

                subConfig.ConfigureConsumer<SomeEventConsumer>(context);
            });

    busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

After submitting another message, I also can see in the logs, that it was skipped, but it is also delivered to *dead letter* queue again.
[screenshot showing a topic and subscription with two items in dead letter queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXokg.png)

So, does this mean that this setting is not accepted by ASB transport? I do not see any change in behaviour, especially the one I expect.

Is it possible to "trully discard" a message that I am not interested in?

### Possible workaround:

I was able to implement desired behaviour with a custom filter that uses *ReceiveContext.IsDelivered* to determine whenever the message was consumed by anyone.

```cs
mtConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busConfig) =>
{
    busConfig.Host(ConnectionString);

    busConfig.SubscriptionEndpoint(
        "testsub",
        "some.topic",
            subConfig =>
            {
                subConfig.ConfigureDeadLetter(x =>
                    {
                        x.UseFilter(new CustomDiscardDeadLetterFilter());
                    });

                subConfig.ConfigureConsumer<SomeEventConsumer>(context);
            });

    busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

```cs
internal class CustomDiscardDeadLetterFilter : IFilter<ReceiveContext>
    {
        public void Probe(ProbeContext context) => context.CreateFilterScope("custom-discard-dead-letter");
    
        public Task Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe<ReceiveContext> next)
        {
            if (!context.IsFaulted && !context.IsDelivered)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            return next.Send(context);
        }
    }
```

I have my doubts about this workaround and this needs to be tested for issues when there are also retries, other filters involved in the pipeline.

Is this workaround close to a proper solution of ignoring unknown messages, or I am missing a lot here?

### Question 3:

Is redesigning our existing eventing architecture to have a single event type per topic the only option to cleanly solve this?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your multiple questions:

1. Subscription endpoints don't have *queues*, so there is no *_error* or *_skipped* queue. By default, all skipped or faulted messages are moved to the DLQ.
2. On normal endpoints, this behavior is configurable. However, because the subscription endpoint already replaces the default empty pipes for skipped/error with filters that move to the DLQ, the pipe is never empty and the discard filter is added *after* the move filter. So, short answer, it's a limitation of the current codebase. I can add an issue, but it will only be fixed in v8.
3. It certainly isn't the only way. The only reason they go to the DLQ is because they're skipped. And the reason should show that (versus being faulted). I can't say that I've built a solution that pushes multiple types into a single topic, but plenty of people have and manage to do it just fine. So, just like everything else in software, *it depends*.

Comment: I think it startyed with misunderstanding of "normal endpoint" and "subscriptiont endpoint" and I expected that _skipped queuee wil be created next to the topic. After that I was digging deeper not realising my mistake.

I do not think it is necessary to create a bug, but (at least for me) it was not clear that DiscardSkippedMessages does not work on SubscriptionEndpoint. Maybe it was stated in docummentation, but I missed it.

Thank you for explanation, and now it is time for me and my team to figure out what option we want to pick.